# Android AccountAuthenticator and OAuth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an Android app using the Windows Live services which uses OAuth2 authentication, therefore I don't have access to the users password. I would like to add the users account to the Android account manager but since I don't have access to the users password, its a spot of problem sticking to the default flow of the account manager i.e. to re-login the user if the auth token is no longer valid. Has anybody built an Android app that uses the account manager for a service that uses OAUth2 for verification? If so how did you handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly doable.  From the Android [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) documentation:

> Many servers support some notion of an authentication token, which can
>   be used to authenticate a request to the server without sending the
>   user's actual password. (Auth tokens are normally created with a
>   separate request which does include the user's credentials.)
>   AccountManager can generate auth tokens for applications, so the
>   application doesn't need to handle passwords directly. Auth tokens are
>   normally reusable and cached by AccountManager, but must be refreshed
>   periodically. It's the responsibility of applications to invalidate
>   auth tokens when they stop working so the AccountManager knows it
>   needs to regenerate them.

Comment: Hey @jengelsma, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.` Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151